# Flutter/Android - Where is the data received from an API temporarily stored? Is there a way to save that data persistently?

Tags: android, api, flutter

I make an API request and get the `Response`, decode it to JSON. Where is this stored? If I have to use the same data without calling the API again **after user restarts the app**, how to I store it to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Where is the data received from an API temporarily stored?**

If you assign it to a local variable in the file then it gets stored in the application's runtime memory.

**Is there a way to save that data persistently?**

Depending on your requirement, you could use number of options.

1. For secure storage of critical data such as access tokens, have a look at  [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)
2. Simple non-critical storage, check [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
3. if you need to store data in a relation db, then see [sqlite](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at Shared Preferences: https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

Or SQLite: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Answer (score 0):

The decoded JSON data is present in the  memory till your app is active. You can store the data in the database if you don't want to make network call again. That way your data will be saved permanently. But still if user closes your app, you need to make sure to get the data from the database and populate the UI.

**Note**: If the data from the API is static, that is, it doesn't change over time then it is good the save the data to the database and getting it back from database. Usually, in API calls, it is not the case(that is, data is not static). In such cases your app  should make network call to the API every time your app starts fresh, that way your data in app is in sync with the server.

Comment: Do **not** use codeblocks for text that is not code.